# Gradle unable to resolve version for dependency

Tags: java, gradle, pax-exam

My project depends on the Pax Exam framework. I declare, among others, these dependencies on Pax (PAX_EXAM_VERSION = 3.4.0):

```
compile group: 'org.ops4j.pax.exam', name: 'pax-exam-junit4', version: PAX_EXAM_VERSION
compile group: 'org.ops4j.pax.exam', name: 'pax-exam-container-native', version: PAX_EXAM_VERSION
```

Both of these depend on `org.ops4j.pax.exam:pax-exam-spi`, which is the module causing my issue.

So, when I try to build my project, the error reported is this one:

`Could not resolve org.ops4j.pax.exam:pax-exam-spi:3.4.0
...
Could not parse POM http://repo.maven.apache.org/maven2/org/ops4j/pax/exam/pax-exam-spi/3.4.0/pax-exam-spi-3.4.0.pom
Unable to resolve version for dependency 'com.google.guava:guava:jar'`

I have tried:

- excluding `pax-exam-spi` from the transitive dependencies of the modules I depend on (but notice I still need the classes in it to be able to compile), adding Guava to my first-level dependencies, then trying to make `pax-exam-spi` a first-level dependency with `transitive = false` (won't work, same problem as above).
- same as above, but instead of doing `transitive = false`, trying to use [artifact-only notation](http://www.gradle.org/docs/current/userguide/dependency_management.html#ssub%3aartifact_dependencies), like this:

  compile "org.ops4j.pax.exam:pax-exam-spi:${PAX_EXAM_VERSION}@jar"

I know the root of the problem is that the guava version is not declared in the `pax-exam-spi pom`, but in its parent `exam`, which only declares the Guava version(s) to use in 2 different profiles' dependencyManagement sessions (this works in Maven because one of the profiles is activated if the property `glassfish.release` is NOT set, and the other if that property IS set). However, knowing this has not been useful so far :(

Please let me know if there's any not-so-hacky way to make sure Gradle does include the `pax-exam-spi`'s jar in my classpath, but does not even try to parse its POM (in particular, referring to a hard-coded path to the jar is out of question!).

Comment: I don't think there is a way to prevent the parsing from happening, but the parsing has recently been improved. I recommend to try with latest 1.12 nightly (easy to apply via Gradle Wrapper). An alternative is to publish `pax-exam-spi` with a "fixed" POM to your enterprise repository.

Comment: What exact version number do I need? 1.12 is not working: java.io.FileNotFoundException: http://downloads.gradle.org/distributions/gradle-1.12-bin.zip

Comment: Here is how to configure wrapper for nigthly build: http://www.gradle.org/nightly and here You can find list of nightly builds: http://services.gradle.org/distributions-snapshots/

Comment: Thanks for the directions, but with the latest 1.12 build, I am getting another error: http://pastebin.com/Zjqb3EJF